# ADB dev-path formatting

Tags: android, linux, windows, adb

I have compiled a custom version of ADB on Linux from the Android source.

I am attempting to deal with devices that have a junk serial number "0123456789ABCDEF" by changing the unique identifier to the devpath not the serial.  The build was successful however the path can't be formatted correctly, shows as "?????????????".

I have executed this on Linux and the path shows correctly, in the format "usb:1.1.1".

Does anyone have any ideas on fixing the windows formatting?  Or any clues that I can work on.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the adb driver for your device from here

`C:\Android\android-adt\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf`

Then go to

`C:\Users\yourname\.android\adb_usb.ini`

and add the VID value manually

Comment: The adb_usb.ini doesn't exist on my machine, I have also already made sure the drivers are installed for the device.  I think it is simply the formatting of hexadecimal characters is invalid on windows.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is relative to below patch. However, for windows part, it seems that the development is NOT ready yet. Not sure whether is plan for windows.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/e109d26%5E!/